# Insert data into a table by selecting from 2 other tables

Tags: mysql, select, insert

Recently I had to insert a new column in one of my tables where I already have hundreds of records.
I want to populate that new column using `INSERT INTO SELECT` query from the other tables. 
The tables are described as below.

`salesman_products` table, where we have a unique `salesman_products_id` for each salesman item and this value shall be inserted into the newly inserted column in the table `inward_log`

```
CREATE TABLE `salesman_products` (
  `salesman_products_id` int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `salesman_id` int(10) NOT NULL
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO `salesman_products` (`salesman_products_id`, `salesman_id`, `product_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 2, 1),
(4, 1, 3),
(5, 2, 2);
```

The second table is `inward` table where we have the `salesman_id`, which shall be used in the query for selecting data from `salesman_products` table

```
CREATE TABLE `inward` (
  `inward_id` int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `salesman_id` int(10) NOT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO `inward` (`inward_id`, `salesman_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 2),
(4, 1),
(5, 2);
```

The third table where I want to fill the column `salesman_product_id`, here we have the primary key of `inward` table as foreign key and also we have `product_id`, which shall be used along with `salesman_id` from inward table to select the `salesman_product_id` from the `salesman_products` table

```
CREATE TABLE `inward_log` (
  `inward_log_id` int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `inward_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `salesman_product_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ;

INSERT INTO `inward_log` (`inward_log_id`, `inward_id`, `product_id`, `salesman_product_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 0),
(2, 1, 1, 0),
(3, 1, 2, 0),
(4, 2, 2, 0),
(5, 2, 1, 0),
(6, 3, 1, 0),
(7, 5, 2, 0);
```

I want to fill the `salesman_product_id` column in the table `inward_log` with `salesman_product_id` from `salesman_products` table

My query is as below, which does not produce the expected result.

```
INSERT INTO inward_log (salesman_product_id)

SELECT salesman_product_id FROM salesman_products
WHERE salesman_id = 
    (SELECT salesman_id FROM inward_log GROUP BY inward_log_id)
AND product_id = 
    (SELECT product_id FROM inward GROUP BY inward_log_id )

order by inward_log_id
```

EXPECTED RESULT in `salesman_product_id` column shall be same as below

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| inward_log_id | inward_id | product_id | salesman_product_id |
+---------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|       1       |     1     |      1     |          1          |
|       2       |     1     |      1     |          1          |
|       3       |     1     |      2     |          2          |
|       4       |     2     |      2     |          2          |
|       5       |     2     |      1     |          1          |
|       6       |     3     |      1     |          3          |
|       7       |     5     |      2     |          5          |
+---------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues with your question : 1. you have not given us the structure of inward_details table, I had to guess that from your expected result section. 2. you have not given us any clue on how your table `inward_products` look like. Please fill out the missing details in your question.

Comment: Apologies @aLuViAn , and thanks for pointing out. I edited the query and made it clear

Comment: More problems exist: there is no `salesman_id` and there is no `inward_log_id` in `inward` table. I assume there are some typos but it actually makes your question invalid. Please copy-and-paste and then run each of the steps you've put in your question and make sure there are no issues, except your question/problem.

Comment: Actually, now everything is fine, we want to insert the data into `inward_log` table, the data shall be taken from `salesman_products` table, now how to take the data from  `salesman_products` table? we should take the `product_id` from `inward_log` table and `salesman_id` from `inward` table and based these 2 criterias we should fetch the `salesman_product_id`. since we don't have the `salesman_id` in the `inward_log` table, therefore we have to take it from `inward` table, which is linked to `inward_log` table

Comment: Seems you've figured it out!